# Upload a file AJAX-ically using Wicket

Tags: java, ajax, file-upload, wicket

I want to upload a file with AJAX in Wicket. It seems to me that Wicket does not support this feature. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the source code from the Wicket Examples for upload: http://www.wicketstuff.org/wicket13/upload/single.  It has examples for both standard and ajax versions.

Comment: it has just ajax progress bar and is not completely ajax

Comment: You are correct, I misinterpreted your question.  Currently, it can't be done with the core wicket libraries but has been written up as an issue, https://cwiki.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-1315.  That issue points to a sample where it has been done with Wicket via an iFrame, http://blog.demay-fr.net/index.php/2007/12/07/93-simulate-ajax-file-upload-with-wicket.

Comment: Update: [WICKET-1315](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-1315) has been closed as a dupe of [WICKET-2420](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-2420).

Comment: I had heard an improvement for this was in the works, but I haven't looked recently.  I thought it was going to be in 1.4, but if the issue is still open, I guess not...

Comment: Link returns 404 status.

Answer (score 1):

As an update to an old question, it seems it is possible right now:

http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/upload

Answer (score 0):

This approach works for me with a full Ajax wicket app.
Sorry, this is Scala syntax but should be easily transferable back to Java syntax:

```
import java.io.File
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.upload.FileUploadField
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget

class TestPage extends WebPage {
    val uploadForm = new Form("form")
    val fileField = new FileUploadField("file")

    uploadForm.add(fileField)
    add(form)

    add(new AjaxSubmitLink("submit", uploadForm) {
        def onSubmit(target: AjaxRequestTarget, form: Form[_]) {
            val upload = fileField.getFileUpload
            if (upload != null) {
                val file: File = upload.writeToTempFile
            }
        }
    })
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd">
<body>

<form wicket:id="form">
    <input wicket:id="file" type="file"/>
</form>
<button wicket:id="submit">Upload</button>

</body>
</html>
```